# How to reduce() on a collection keeping the collection itself in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I just need to reduce the elements in a collection but I'd like to keep the collection in the result.

```
scala> List("a","b","c").reduce(_+_)
res0: String = abc
```

I'd like to get

```
scala> List("a","b","c").someSortOfReduce(_+_)
res0: List[String] = List(abc)

scala> Seq("a","b","c").someSortOfReduce(_+_)
res1: Seq[String] = Seq(abc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it (maybe not the most elegant, but hey, it works):

```
import collection.generic._
def reduceAsCollection[E,C[_]](s: C[E])(f: (E,E) => E)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, E, C[E]], e: C[E] <:< TraversableOnce[E]): C[E] = {
  (cbf() += s.reduce(f)).result
}
```

And the obligatory REPL test:

```
scala> reduceAsCollection(List("a","b","c"))(_+_)
res14: List[String] = List(abc)

scala> reduceAsCollection(Seq("a","b","c"))(_+_)
res15: Seq[String] = Vector(abc)
```

As you can see, not only has the resulting collection an appropriate runtime type, but the static type is also preserved (give a `Seq` get a `Seq` back, give a `List`, get a `List` back).

Comment: It's too bad you can't just get an implicit `Builder[E, C[E]]` in this case and avoid the `Nothing`.  Do you know why the libraries chose not to expose implicit `Builders` as well as `CanBuildFroms`?

Comment: I would guess that they did not want to introduce yet another construct just for the sake of removing a type parameter. But nothing prevents you from doing `type Builder[-Elem, +To] = CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Elem, To]`.

Comment: Oh my bad, you were talking about `scala.collection.mutable.Builder`, right? Well, you clearly don't want to have a Builder be passed implicitly, as it is inherently mutable. You create a builder locally, add elements to it, get a collection back, and then toss the builder, which should never leak outside. So you really want to get passed (implicitly) something that let's you create a **fresh** builder, and that's what a`CanBuildFrom` is.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `companion` method

```
def red[T](a: Iterable[T], f: (T,T) => T) = a.companion(a.reduce(f))
```

**EDITED**

If you need to preserve the static type an option is to use `asInstanceOf`

```
implicit class Reduce[T, C[T] <: Iterable[T]](s: C[T]) {
  def someSortOfReduce(f: (T, T) => T): C[T] = s.companion(s.reduce(f)).asInstanceOf[C[T]]
}
val list = List(1, 2, 3).someSortOfReduce(_ + _)  // list: List[Int] = List(6)
val set = Set(1, 2, 3).someSortOfReduce(_ + _)    // set: Set[Int] = Set(6)
```

or Pattern Matching

```
implicit class Reduce[T, C[T] <: Iterable[T]](s: C[T]) {
  def someSortOfReduce(f: (T, T) => T): C[T] = s.companion(s.reduce(f)) match {
    case a: C[T] => a
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in your code: it should be `a.companion(a.reduce(f))`. Even then, there is still the problem that the (static) return type is always `Iterable[T]`, when we'll really want to have it be the same type as the input collection.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself

```
val list = List("a","b","c")
list.companion(list.reduce(_+_))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if you're going to use this code everytime you need to do this, you could as well just do `List(list.reduce(_+_))`. After all, you do know that `list`'s type is `List`. If your intent is to move it inside a method that you can call at will, you'll basically end up with LRLucena's solution, in which case you'll lose the static type and always get the same collection type as a result, regardless of the original collection type.

Answer (score 0):

Since the collection you want and the original collection don't share any entries, you could just wrap the result of the reduce in whatever you want.

```
Seq(original.reduce(_+_))
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to get the same collection automatically. That's why I found a similar more portable solution